# HTML Table crashing NetSuite when I try to print multiple rows (Advanced PDF)

Tags: html, pdf, html-table, netsuite, html-to-pdf

I'm trying to print the detail on a check in NetSuite using the HTML portion of the Advanced PDF functionality.

I'm printing a table using HTML, where the top row is the header, and the remaining rows are the data i'd like to display. The check contains multiple bills, and I would like to display the details of these multiple bills.

The code I'm using is below. I print the header row, and then attempt to print the details rows.

The issue I'm facing: I can print 1 row just fine, but when I try to print multiple rows, NetSuite crashes and gives me the following error message: "*An unexpected error has occurred. Please click here to notify support and provide your contact information.*"

```
<#if check.apply?has_content><#list check.apply as apply>
<table style="position: absolute;overflow: hidden;left: 36pt;top: 15pt;width: 436pt;border-collapse: collapse;border: 2px solid black;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Date</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Description</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Orig. Amt.</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Amt. Due</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Discount</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Amount</font></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>${apply.applydate}</td>
            <td>${apply.refnum}</td>
            <td>${apply.total}</td>
            <td>${apply.due}</td>
            <td>${apply.disc}</td>
            <td>${apply.amount}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</#list></table>
</#if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this "<#list check.apply as apply>" should be placed after "`</thead>`" since you only want the table header to be created once. Something like this

```
<#if check.apply?has_content>
<table style="position: absolute;overflow: hidden;left: 36pt;top: 15pt;width: 436pt;border-collapse: collapse;border: 2px solid black;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Date</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Description</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Orig. Amt.</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Amt. Due</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Discount</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#000000"><font color="white">Amount</font></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<#list check.apply as apply>
        <tr>
            <td>${apply.applydate}</td>
            <td>${apply.refnum}</td>
            <td>${apply.total}</td>
            <td>${apply.due}</td>
            <td>${apply.disc}</td>
            <td>${apply.amount}</td>
        </tr>
</#list>
    </tbody>
</table>
</#if>
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks a lot.